# Knockout JS value not showing/binding/updating but is available through ko.toJS($data).value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a strange problem, at least I think it is strange.

The following will show nothing:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedAddress.street1" />
```

But, if binded like this then it shows the correct value, but doesn't update (shows the value but does not seem to bind to object):

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: ko.toJS($data).selectedAddress.street1" />
```

I checked if the selectedAddress object actually contains data with:

```
JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(selectedAddress), null, 2)
```

And it does

```
{
 "id": 5631,
 "street1": "Some Adress 43",
 "street2": null,
 "postcode": "15850",
 "city": "GhostTown",
 "country": "UK",
 "addressTypes": []
}
```

**How to get the input field to correctly bind to the object property and display/update value accordingly?**

ViewModel:

```
var theViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.no = ko.observable();
        self.name = ko.observable();
        self.addresses = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.selectedAddress = ko.observable(new Address());
        ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `data-bind="value: selectedAddress().street1"` - I'm not sure whether implicit parenthesis are supported when concatenating observables.

Comment: Niko,  wanna do that as an answer, so it can be accepted? :)

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I've summed it up in a few sentences, please accept my answer in order to communicate clearly that the answer to this question has been found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parenthesis are optional only in some cases, but not when referring to a property of an object (that may or may not be the value of an observable). Therefore, you need to explicitly use parenthesis to get the value of the observable `selectedAddress`. Then, you may refer to the property `street1` of this object (parenthesis are now optional):

```
data-bind="value: selectedAddress().street1"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is solution for one-way binding (value will not be updated).

Here is quote from KnockoutJS documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

> If you reference something that is not a simple property, e.g., a complex JavaScript expression or a sub-property, KO will set the form element’s initial state to that value, but it will not be able to write any changes back when the user edits the form element. In this case it’s a one-time-only value setter, not a real binding.

To get two-way binding functionality, use templates.
Something like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="someTemplate">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: street1" />
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'someTemplate', data: selectedAddress }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone had the same issue and wondered about this part

```
self.selectedAddress = ko.observable(new Address());
```

And you might ask whether there's a need to create a constructor or an object to fill up the ko.observable function, well you can, but if you don't like creating a model for this one, just add up an empty array and the parenthesis method should work.

example :

```
self.selectedAddress = ko.observable([]);
```

then :

```
selectedAddres().street1
```

This may not work for other instances but so far it worked on me. Thank you for this answer too, saved me a lot of time!